# Need help in solving "unexpected end of file" exception?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to transform below 2 statements into a shell script

```
cat all5.log | grep 'Opened\|Closed'> all.log
awk -F ' ' '{print }' all.log | sort | uniq > uniqueFiles.txt
```

Here is monitorFd.sh bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "" != "" ]; then
    cat  | grep 'Opened\|Closed' > temp.log
    awk -F ' ' '{print }' temp.log | sort | uniq > uniqueFiles.txt

    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        cmd1=`cat  | grep Opened | grep $line | sort | wc -l`
        cmd2=`cat  | grep Closed | grep $line | sort | wc -l`
        echo 'Opened: '$cmd1', Closed: '$cmd2' '$line
    done < "uniqueFiles.txt"

    rm -f temp.log
else
    echo "No target file provided. (hint: trace dump of file-leak-detector.jar)"  #syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

In notepad++ I changed this file to be of UNIX format. Also changed permission to +x, but I am getting below exception.

```
monitorFd.sh: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

[image]

What is wrong with this program?

Comment: `if ... else ... fi`

Comment: @xxfelixxx: Thanks this solve my issue.

Comment: @xxfelixxx: For future such issues, do have a look at http://shellcheck.net . That's a great framework & can be integrated in your editor... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Syntax for `if` in bash is `if ... else/elif ... fi`. So just add a `fi` at the end of your file.